# Invalid default for field warning message coming from Avro?

Tags: java, boolean, avro

I have a avro schema like this in which I have `is_userid_present` decalred as boolean and I wanted to give default value as false to it so I came up with below avro schema.

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"hello",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"u",
         "type":[
            "string",
            "null"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"p",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"bu",
         "type":"boolean"
      },
      {
         "name":"is_userid_present",
         "type":"boolean",
         "default":"false"
      }
   ]
}
```

But from Avro code, I am seeing this warning message -

```
[WARNING] Avro: Invalid default for field is_userid_present: "false" not a "boolean"
```

I am not sure what wrong I am doing here? If I have avro schema like this, then will it be of any problem for writing and reading the data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Avro Docs](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/spec.html), if you specify a default boolean, you can't do it as a `String` like you have it.

Try this...

```
  {
     "name": "is_userid_present",
     "type": "boolean",
     "default": false
  }
```